# Change animation property from <circle>-element with angularjs

Tags: angular, svg, css-animations

For my web app I created a countdown timer where you can set any time. Now I want to make an animated circle around the countdown for better visualization. The duration of the animation depends on the size of the countdown.

The HTML looks like this:

```
 <mat-card-content class="timerTime">
                <svg width="200" height="200">
                    <circle id="timer1circle" class="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="80" style="animation: 300s circletimer linear"/>
                </svg>
                <span class="timer-text">{{timer1Rest}}</span>
            </mat-card-content>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
@keyframes circletimer {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
    stroke-dasharray: 500;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 500;
  }
}

svg {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateZ(-90deg);
}

.circle {
  stroke: rgba(226, 149, 120, 1);
  stroke-width: 16;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  animation: 300s circletimer linear;
}

.timer-text {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #006D77;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

The animation works fine with the static value 300s.

Is it possible that I can change the value "300s" via AngularJS? I already have a function that calculates the seconds I need. I would like to exchange this value with the 300s.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an extra `<style>` tag:

```html
<style id="circleduration">
  circle {
    animation-duration: 300s;
  }
</style>
```

Then use JavaScript to update it:

```js
document.getElementById("circleduration").innerText = `animation-duration:666s`;
```

This works great if you need to change more CSS

You could also stick the `animation-duration` on the circle itself:

```js
document.querySelector("circle").style.animationDuration = `666s`;
```

**FYI:** there was a Native JavaScript Web Component `<event-count>` on my ToDo list once;
it is unlicensed source code:

https://event-count.github.io/

```html
<script src="https://event-count.github.io/element.min.js"></script>

<style>
    event-count::part(event) {
        font-size: 1rem;
        background: gold;
        color: blue;
    }
    event-count::part(count) {
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    }
    event-count::part(year) {
        color: beige;
    }
</style>

<event-count format="es">Y2K38 Date Problem <!-- in Spanish language --> </event-count>

<hr>

<event-count count="day,hour" event="2024-1-1"> New Year! </event-count>
```